# React Table is showing previous state rather than current state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, material-ui, use-effect

I am trying to set up a sorted data table using React and Material-UI, but I am having some trouble with the data showing correctly on state change.

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import Table from '@material-ui/core/Table';
import TableHead from '@material-ui/core/TableHead';
import TableBody from '@material-ui/core/TableBody';
import TableRow from '@material-ui/core/TableRow';
import TableCell from '@material-ui/core/TableCell';
import TableSortLabel from '@material-ui/core/TableSortLabel';

const columnData = [
    {id: "id", label: "ID"},
    {id: "city", label: "City"}
];

const rowData = [
    {id: 1, city: "Chicago"},
    {id: 2, city: "New York"},
    {id: 3, city: "Detroit"}
];

const DataTable = (props) => {
    const { columns, data } = props;

    const [sortBy, setSortBy] = useState("id");
    const [sortDirection, setSortDirection] = useState("asc");
    const [sortedData, setSortedData] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        const newData = data;
        newData.sort((a,b) => {
            // sort according to sortBy and sortDirection
        }
        
        setSortedData(newData);
    }, [sortBy, sortDirection, setSortedData]);

    const handleSortChange = (columnId) => {
        setSortDirection(sortBy === columnId && sortDirection === "asc" ? "desc" : "asc");
        setSortBy(columnId);
    }

    return (
         <Table>
             <TableHead>
                 <TableRow>
                     {columns.map(column => (
                         <TableCell key={column.id}/>
                             <TableSortLabel
                                 active={sortBy === column.id}
                                 direction={sortDirection}
                                 onClick={() => handleSortChange(column.id)}
                             >
                                 {column.label}
                             </TableSortLabel>
                         </TableCell>
                     ))}
                 </TableRow>
             </TableHead>
             <TableBody>
                 {sortedData.map(row => {
                     console.log(row.id);

                     return (
                         <TableRow key={row.id}>
                             {Object.keys(row).map(columnId => (
                                 <TableCell key={`${row.id}_${columnId}`}>
                                     ...
                                 </TableCell>
                             )}
                         </TableRow>
                     )
                 )}
             </TableBody>
         </Table>
    );
}
```

I pass in the column metadata and table data as props and the table gets constructed using that information. When a user clicks on the header cell, `sortBy` and `sortDirection` get updated, which triggers the effect hook which sorts the data and then updates the state with that sorted data.

My issue is that the rows of data being shown do not reflect the what is in the state at the time of rendering. Instead, the table is always showing the previous state. I added the `console.log` to confirm that the rows are correctly sorted in the returned JSX.

*Initial render*

Console: `1 2 3`

| ID | City |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Chicago |
| 2 | New York |
| 3 | Detroit |

*Click on City header*

Console: `1 3 2`

| ID | City |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Chicago |
| 2 | New York |
| 3 | Detroit |

*Click on ID header*

Console: `1 2 3`

| ID | City |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Chicago |
| 3 | Detroit |
| 2 | New York |

No matter what I try, it always shows the previous state. Can anyone explain what I am doing wrong?

Comment: shouldn't your useffect use `[sortBy, sortDirection, sortedData]` instead?

Comment: `[sortBy, sortDirection]` even, but this might not fix your issue.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that sort returns an array, but you're not updating the state with it. Try this:

```
useEffect(() => {
    const newData = data.sort((a,b) => {
        // sort according to sortBy and sortDirection
    }
    
    setSortedData(newData);
}, [sortBy, sortDirection]);
```